# Finding out list text when a connected sortable is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have connected sortable list and I want to have a callback function for double click on the list elements. Is there a standard way to figure out what is the html/text content of the item that was clicked? I am doing the following on chrome but it does not work on Firefox.

```
//when element is dropped in connected sortable
ui.item[0].ondblclick = wordClicked;

function wordClicked(e) {
    console.log(e.srcElement.innerText);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use jQuery methods as jQuery is built to work on all browsers.

For your double click event handler you can use this http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

And to get the text of an element you can use this http://api.jquery.com/text/

I've created this jsFiddle that shows how both methods work http://jsfiddle.net/davew9999/7cQXX/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

<div id="result"></div>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("ul li").dblclick(function() {
    $("#result").text("You double clicked " + $(this).text());
});​
```

Comment: Thanks. $(this).text() works for events too and solved my problem! So my final solution became -

`function wordClicked(e) { console.log($(this).text()); }`

Answer (score 0):

fox not supports 'innerText' in this situation

Comment: as @David Williams answered, $(this).text() words across browsers for events also!